# How to randomize IP address with requests module in Python?

Tags: python, nginx, python-requests

Is it possible if we can randomize IP address by using `requests` module? For instance the `access.log` in nginx is

```
110.54.222.139 - - [29/Jun/2018:03:00:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4785 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/10.10 Chromium/10.0.642.0 Chrome/10.0.642.0 Safari/534.1"
```

can we randomize an ip address to make:

```
RANDOM_IP_ADDRESS - - [29/Jun/2018:03:00:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4785 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/10.10 Chromium/10.0.642.0 Chrome/10.0.642.0 Safari/534.1"
```

Comment: The IP address isn't included within the HTTP request (it's several layers below) so you can't accomplish this with the requests module.

Comment: Kind of... maybe. (there's x-forwarded-for which nginx could use) But this feels like an [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Could you say what do you want to achieve this way? Do you want to generate those logs for yourself, or spoof results on some remove service? Debug some nginx issue?

Comment: @viraptor To spoof results in remote servers. I am not sure if a website will block my server's IP address if I continue to use that IP. I aggregate their feed every now and then.

Comment: Why do you need `requests` module to do this? `requests` is for making HTTP calls. You can easily randomize an IP-address using `random.randint`.

Comment: @blhsing There might be a confusion with what I'm asking. We can randomize the headers with `requests` so I'm asking if can we do it also for the IP address?

Comment: You'd need proxies.

Answer (score 4):

> I am not sure if a website will block my server's IP address if I continue to use that IP. I aggregate their feed every now and then.

You can't do that (legally/easily...) without actually being able to send traffic from another source address.

If you really want to avoid getting blocked, look at ways to tunnel your traffic through other places. For example: starting your process on a new hosted instance, using vpns, tor.

Comment: I would add that it's a technical problem: While it can be possible to send requests with a spoofed source IP, the server isn't going to be able to respond to your machine since it will try to send the response to the (spoofed) source IP. (Which isn't you) @viraptor's solution of VPNs or other machines (virtual or physical) is the only way this could work

Comment: By the not legal/easy ways, I meant bgp attacks, which do happen, but are not practical in any way. Just a sidenote for the curious.